# Java Jsoup: How should I extract the following data point from this html?

Tags: java, jsoup, data-extraction

I am trying to extract the latest info from the following :

Below is the html code that I am looking at, but I have no idea how to tackle this problem using Jsoup? The problem is that there are many classes called "UL1", multiple "Last" and many "td" within the html . 
I need to get the current price which is "31.4" in this case.

```
<td rowspan="2" class="bg1 W1">
           <ul class="UL1"><li class="LI1 font12_grey W1">Last</li></ul>
           <ul class="UL1"><li class="LI2 font28 C bold W1"><span class="neg bold">31.400</span></li></ul>
           <ul class="UL1 none" style="display:none;"><li class="LI1 C W1">
          <img src="/en/Images/Stock/icon_see.gif" border=0 /><a id="ctl00_ctl00_cphContent_cphContent_lnkAddMonitor" class="font12a" href="#">Monitor</a><img src="/en/Images/Stock/icon_group.gif" border=0 /><a id="ctl00_ctl00_cphContent_cphContent_lnkAddPortfolio" class="font12a" href="#">Portfolio</a> 
           </li></ul>
           </td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look for the `ul` element that contains the text `Last` then find the next sibling:

```
ul:contains(Last) + ul>li>span
```

You can find a demo [here](http://try.jsoup.org/~8_23WvpObTiz80J6PTouulVzPYM).

Comment: Hi, I would like to ask what does ":" and ">" mean in your code? I am still trying to figure out how to use jsoup. Thanks

Comment: @mynameisJEFF: you can find the answers on the Jsoup guide: http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html